# SQL case Statement to handle "divide by zero" ignores condition THEN 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case

Here is the SQL:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN Field1 = 0 THEN 0 
    ELSE SUM((Field1 - Field2 * Field3)/Field1) 
END
```

This and variations of it return the divide by zero error every time Field1 = 0

Need to look away, I'm sure the answer is obvious.

Thanks

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try wrapping the sum on the outer:

`sum(CASE WHEN Field1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((Field1 - Field2 * Field3)/Field1) END)`

Comment: Simon1979, that did the trick, thanks a lot for the quick reply and lesson. Cheers